WinError 10060 while trying to connect client to server?
I'm currently programming a barebones proxy server in Python for a class. I'm trying to connect my client-socket on the proxy to whatever website the user requested. However, whenever I try to connect the socket, I get a timeout, specifically [WinError 10060]. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
(This is built off skeleton code given to me by my professor, so if there's any outdated methods included, that's probably by design)
Relevant segment of code:
        if not fileExist:
            # Create a socket on the proxyserver
            c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            # clear any mess from filename so address can be properly requested
            hostn = filename.replace(b"www.", b"", 1)
            print(hostn.decode())
            try:
                # Connect the socket to port 80
                c.bind(('', 80))
                # get address info for the requested url
                addrList = getaddrinfo(hostn, 80)
                # uses a valid IP/value pair from addrList as target 
                c.connect(addrList[0][4])
                # this line never prints, meaning the connection is the problem
                print("connected")

Expected: connection between my socket and the server's socket
Result: infinite waiting
